# iframe load especific DIV from an external link?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a page with a IFRAME. An iframe that loads an external link: http://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B144/

The problem is that the page loads the default sport (Horse Racing). I would like that the iframe load other virtual sport, like 'Soccer' for example.

Tha problem is that the Soccer doesn't have an especific link, but only an especific DIV. It's necessary a manual click to select this sport.

In that case, it's possible to make an iframe that loads an especific div from an especific external link?

Comment: And by <div> you mean an entry from the menu on the left? If so, they seem to have a specific link and you could just use this one. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: yes, you can load url from the page using javascript something like window.frames[iframeName].location = url;

Comment: Can you paste the relevant chunk of code of the site you are trying to reference via your iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reach the site, which tells me in Romanian that my access has been restricted. To help you I am assuming the `div` elements you are talking about have `id`s. Let's suppose that the div containing soccer has the `id` of `"soccer"`. In this case you can have the following `src` for your `iframe`: `yoururl#soccer`.